Too many Observables
In a project I work on I stumbled upon a Service, that creates Several Observables in a row, and it looks like this:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventCatcherService

  private destroy$ = new Subject();
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(null);
  }

  init(): void {
        this.eventService.get(Event1)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$),tap((evt) => this.doEcondaTracking1(evt)))
          .subscribe();
        this.eventService.get(Event2)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$),tap((evt) => this.doEcondaTracking2(evt)))
          .subscribe();
        this.eventService.get(Event3)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$),tap((evt) => this.doEcondaTracking3(evt)))
          .subscribe();
    ...

So Basically the idea was to handle certain Tracking Operations within one File/Service instead of spreading it across all the dedicated components.
This is why all those events are prefetched and observed in advance.
I wonder if that is good practice for performance's sake.
Since they are all unsubscribed from by receiving the "takeUntil"-Operator, it shouldn't be too bad. Testing performance with google Chromes lighthouse and performance Tool did now indicate any significant difference removing those subscriptions.
Do you think that this code is performance proof or should this be refactored?

In itself not really an issue. You could remove some duplication by using a forkJoin for example..

Seems ok to me, you can create a generate function, that will take care of setting  up the observables with the least amount of code and a single subscribe.
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject, merge, takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs';

export const Event1 = 'Event1';
export const Event2 = 'Event2';
export const Event3 = 'Event3';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class EventCatcherService {
  private destroy$ = new Subject();
  listenerMap = {
    Event1: this.doEcondaTracking1.bind(this),
    Event2: this.doEcondaTracking2.bind(this),
    Event3: this.doEcondaTracking3.bind(this),
  };
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next(null);
  }
  doEcondaTracking1() {}
  doEcondaTracking2() {}
  doEcondaTracking3() {}

  createListeners(listenerMap: Object): Array<Observable<any>> {
    const output: Array<Observable<any>> = [];
    Object.entries(listenerMap).forEach(([eventType, value]: any) => {
      output.push(
        this.eventService.get(eventType).pipe(
          takeUntil(this.destroy$),
          tap((evt: any) => value(evt))
        )
      );
    });
    return output;
  }

  init(): void {
    merge(...this.createListeners(this.listenerMap)).subscribe();
  }
}

